# What are the possible values of HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH?

Tags: http

Is it possible (or usual) for the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header to have any other value than `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: Possible? Certainly yes. It's a header. Anybody can pass whatever they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That header is not registered with the [IANA Message Headers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml) and is thus not subject to any formal specification. The MDN is alsop coming up [empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Requested-With), so there will hardly be an exhaustive list of allowed values. Just be prepared for requests not carrying the value `XMLHttpRequest` in that header to not be recognised as issued via Ajax.